# Getting jquery Errors

Tags: jquery, html, joomla

I am trying to open Nonumber Modal on page load.
this is my site [url](https://www.joomconnect.com/popup-test) (wait for 10 sec).
I am opening a Joomconnect form inside this modal but when it opens , giving me jQuery errors.
I tried to resolved it but didn't get any solution
screenshot : jquery error

[image]

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function

Code :

```
<p><a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;id=467&amp;tmpl=component" id="popup_onload" class="modal" style="display: none;">Signup</a></p>
```

Comment: You should post the problem code in your question and details of your problem or question.

Comment: The first error usually happens when you make an AJAX request expecting a JSON response, but actually receive HTML - most likely due to a 404 or 500 error. You should really post your code in the question though. No one is going to trawl through the DOM inspector on your website.

Comment: I have added my code which i am using to open the modal , actually i am opening an article in a modal.

Comment: please add more details: source code or link directly on your popup not worked modal form

Comment: I have already added the source link to my site "url" , no problem click on this https://www.joomconnect.com/popup-test